# Tiny C Compiler: file '/usr/lib/crt1.o/ not found

Tags: linux, c

При компиляции tcc версии 0.9.25 в ОС Slitaz 4.0 командой

> tcc main.c -o main.o

выдаёт ошибки

> tcc: file '/usr/lib/crt1.o/ not found
>   tcc: file '/usr/lib/crti.o/ not found
>   tcc: file '/usr/lib/crtn.o/ not found

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить в систему пакет glibc командой

> tazpkg get-install glibc

Затем перезапустить компиляцию.